# showing pre-rolled ads using Video.js in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, video, next.js, ads, video.js

I'm working on a video player with Next.js and video.js, and I'm having trouble showing preroll ads. I want to display a preroll ad before the video starts playing, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've tried looking for solutions online, but I haven't been able to find anything that works with my setup. I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me some guidance on how to implement preroll ads in video.js with Next.js.

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
import "videojs-contrib-hls";

const VideoPlayerVideoJs = ({ video }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(videoRef.current, {
      sources: [
        {
          src: video?.url,
        },
      ],
      liveui: true,
      preload: false,
      autoplay: true,
      muted: video?.categoryName === "LiveTV",
    });

    player.on("timeupdate", () => {
      const videoDuration = player.duration();
      const currentTime = player.currentTime();
      const timeLeft = videoDuration - currentTime;
    });
  }, [videoRef, video]);

  return (
    <div>
      <video
        id="playerId"
        controls
        ref={videoRef}
        muted={video?.categoryName === "LiveTV"}
        className="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9 vjs-fluid vjs-user-inactive vjs-controls-enabled vjs-workinghover vjs-waiting vjs-has-started vjs-live vjs-liveui-enabled vjs-touch-enabled"
        data-setup='{"fluid": true}'
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayerVideoJs;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

I attempted to use the "videojs-contrib-ads" plugin in order to display pre-roll advertisements, however I encountered difficulties and was unable to implement this feature successfully. I also tried utilizing the "videojs-vast-vpaid" plugin as an alternative solution, but encountered a separate error related to a global CSS issue associated with the plugin.